# Decent J2ME developer communities for China, Japan, Taiwan, HK?

Tags: java-me, mobile

We're evaluating a potential investment opportunity to port our J2ME applications from English/UK to Far Eastern markets. We're having trouble finding ANY information about things such as handsets, platforms, etc., and in particular, operator/carrier policies regarding supported network functionality and policies.

We have reams of questions so I think the best place to start would be some **developer community sites**, but we can't find any that are both English and up to date. If you know of any please fire away!

I guess the overriding question is **would it be the done thing to build a J2ME midlet,  that uses TCP sockets extensively, and expect to be able to port it and distribute it in these markets?** Do many handsets support J2ME? Will the operators allow sockets out-of-the-box? And every other question I can think of right now... apologies but we don't know where to start!

- Handsets (models, market share, resolutions, J2ME support)
- Operators (market share, walled garden policies, data tariffs)
- Distribution (aggregators, app stores, operator portals)
- Test Houses (every handset, every operator, localisation)

Comment: For the developer communities you are looking for, here's the most popular list:
[Programmer's Club, which hosts a wide variety forums](http://www.programmer-club.com.tw/) [Java World TW, forums in which mainly focus on Java-related topics](http://www.javaworld.com.tw/jute/)

Answer (score 1):

J2ME is pretty much supported everywhere. I´ve ported some applications to Korean and Hebrew, so my advice is this:

- Get in contact with service provider in the market you wish enter, they can give you plenty of information about handsets and distribution, data tariffs, etc;
- TCP connection is available on every J2me capable device I´ve seen, but you should confirm that for your target handsets before porting to them;
- You should REALLY be carefull when localising your application, bad translations will make your users hate you

I´ll will edit this answers as I think of more advice, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

How about consult to the VM vendors inside these area, for instance: Aplix or Esmertec?

It's not that easy to find a community using English instead of native language.

# I'm from Taiwan, and AFAIK, most handsets here are sold with J2ME included. But in Japan market, DOJA is the profile they use. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some operators will not allow you tcp sockets at all but let HTTP connections through.